# NSInvalidArgumentException reason : unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wanted to contribute something back, since everyone here has been so responsive. I was getting the above error on an action "button". It was driving me crazy. You see I have a master/detail template and I added an extra detail view to my project. I had a button on the second detail view, but not on the first. I took all of the code out of the button action and still received the error, so I added the same button to the first detail view ... and what do you know it worked.

```
-(IBAction) addData_btn: (sender){

    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [array addObject:AcctName.text];
    [array addObject:AcctNum.text];
    [array addObject:DayDue.text];
    [array addObject:paymnt.text];
    [array addObject:remBalance.text];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *plistPath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts.plist"];

    [array writeToFile:plistPath atomically: true];
}
```

I added same button to first detail view, without any code ... it worked.

Comment: This makes no sense. You are saying that you fixed a problem in one view controller by needlessly adding an unneeded button on another view controller? That's not the proper way to fix a bug.

Comment: If you show us that full error message, it will tell us what method was attempted to be invoked for what sort of object. That will help us diagnose what's going on.

Comment: while I agree that it is NOT proper, it somehow corrected the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that, on Interface Builder, you didn't left any connections on buttons to actions that do not exist on their correspondent ViewControllers. Or else, the button, when touched, will try to call a method that doesn't exists, throwing this exception.

Comment: Or if you use CoreData, that you added the property in the model file.

Answer (score 0):

if your issue is happening where you have more than one detailViewControllers ... add same button or fields to the other detailViewcontroller. it should take care of issue. Good Luck